# How to import a "no-namespace" XML schema into WSDL?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl, xerces

I have an XML schema (called DataQualityCalculationTasks.xsd) that did not declare a target namespace http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#UndeclaredTNS. I imported this XML schema in my WSDL file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wsdl:definitions 
targetNamespace="http://example.com/myNamespace" 
name="DataQualityServiceService" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="DataQualityCalculationTasks.xsd"/>
</wsdl:types>

..................................................................

</wsdl:definitions>
```

However, I get the following error in eclipse:

> src-import.1.2: If the namespace attribute is not present on an  element information item then the enclosing schema must have a targetNamespace. The error comes from the XML parser Apache Xerces.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could to do it as below:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:tempuri-org">
        <xsd:import schemaLocation="DataQualityCalculationTasks.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried it but I get two errors. The first error states "src-import.3.1: The namespace attribute,' ', of an <import> element information item must be identical to the targetNamespace attribute, 'null', of the imported document." The second error is in my WSDL file where I try to use an element defined in the imported schema like this <wsdl:message name="calculateRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:calculate"/>
    <wsdl:part name="reqHeader" element="DataQualityCalculationTasks"/>
  </wsdl:message>

Comment: Make sure that there is no namespace attribute in the xsd:import (see the post)... can you confirm it? If you don't have it, then change the xsd:import to an xsd:include and remove the targetNamespace="urn..." from the xsd:schema. Both are valid...

Comment: My WSDL file now looks like this <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:tempuri-org">
    <xsd:import namespace="" schemaLocation="DataQualityCalculationTasks.xsd"/>
   </xsd:schema>

Comment: @Peter, remove the namespace="" attribute (see the post). That's what is causing the issue.

Comment: The XSD I am trying to import has no namespace attribute at all. Therefore I tried your second solution (xsd:include and removed the targetNamespace="urn..."). The errors are gone and now I have a warning (which is much better): "WS-I: (BP2107) A xsd:schema element contained in wsdl:types element does not have a targetNamespace attribute with a valid and non-null value, while having child element(s) other than xsd:import or xsd:annotation." What does this warning mean? Is there a way to eliminate this warning?

Comment: The post should also work (without namespace); in general, that is how you import a no-namespace schema in a schema with target namespace. WS-I recommends using namespaces; it means that you're also defining some other schema things (elements and/or types most likely)... and since you're not defining a targetNamespace... You should try it the way I wrote the post; eventually change to urn: to something else that is more appropriate in your case.

Comment: OK, I have switched back to the import, removed the namespace="" attribute and all the errors and warning are gone. Thank you, it worked!